# is there any deployment automation software that can create an encrypted vm in esxi?

Tags: vmware-esxi, ansible, vmware-vsphere, automation, terraform

I recently felt the need to encrypt my esxi vms and tried to find some way to do it with terraform but couldn't find an option for that in the documentation so I looked into ansible , chef with no luck. So my question is that is there anyway I could create an encrypted vm or encrypt an existing one using automation other than the vmware vsphere api since that thing is a mess.

Comment: There's a whole encrypted VM storage profile bit in vCenter - it's not hard to setup and then just automatically does it.

Comment: Indeed that sounds exactly like what I need, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a whole encrypted VM storage profile bit in vCenter - it's not hard to setup and then just automatically does it.